# Collatz algorithm in c

Tags: c

The next code displays the number of steps needed for a positive integer below 100 to get to the first 1 using the Collatz algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i, num;
    int pasos;
    for(i=2;i<=100;i++){
        pasos=0;
        num=i;
        while(num!=1){
            if(num%2 == 0){
                num = num/2;
                pasos=pasos+1;
            }
            else
            {
                num = num*3 + 1;
                pasos=pasos+1;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde %i fueron: %i",i,pasos);
    }
```

I know that 97 is the number below 100 that needs the biggest number of steps(118) to get to the first 1, but how can I make the program display this biggest number instead of looking for it in the program output? I hope you understand, english is not my first language. Thanks!

Comment: Store the current largest found in a separate variable, if the one you got from the current iteration is larger, replace it.

Comment: could you help me? I don´t know where to put that variable, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, as one approach to collecting the maximum number, you can simply add a `ternary` expression following your `while` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int i=0, num=0;
    int pasos=0, maxpasos=0;;
    for (i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        pasos = 0;
        num = i;
        while (num != 1) {
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                num = num / 2;
                pasos = pasos + 1;
            }

            else {
                num = num * 3 + 1;
                pasos = pasos + 1;
            }
        }
        maxpasos = (pasos > maxpasos) ? pasos : maxpasos;
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde %i fueron: %i", i,
                pasos);
    }
    printf ("\n\nMaxpasos : %d\n\n", maxpasos);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
./bin/collatzmax

El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde 2 fueron: 1
El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde 3 fueron: 7
El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde 4 fueron: 2
(snip)
El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde 99 fueron: 25
El numero de pasos para llegar a 1 desde 100 fueron: 25

Maxpasos : 118
```

If you also need to store `i` when it occurs, simply add a variable `int imax=0;`, then when you store `maxpaso`, also store `imax=i;`. Example:

```
int i=0, num=0, imax=0;
...
    // maxpasos = (pasos > maxpasos) ? pasos : maxpasos;
    if (pasos > maxpasos) {
        maxpasos = pasos;
        imax = i;
    }
```

**output:**

```
Maxpasos (at 97): 118
```